# Match every word, including non-a-z digits

Tags: reactjs, regex

I'm really struggling to get a regex working.  All I want to do is something that would capture a string and its trailing space and put that as an entry into an array.

For example:

```
"RegExr #was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.
```

Edit the Expression & Text to see matches."

```
["RegExr ", "#was ", "created ",  "by ", gskinner.com " ... "& " ... "matches. "  etc...]
```

I'm trying to do the following in a React App:

```
console.log("matches are: ", message.match(/(\w+\s|#\w+\s|\s )/));
return message.match(/((\w+ ?))/);
// return message.split(" ");
```

I found that the split function was created some weird issues for me so I wanted just to have the matches function return an array of the results I specified above.

When I log out some attempts I just get weird results no matter what I try, like this:

e.g.

```
matches are:  (2) ["Hey ", "Hey ", index: 0, input: "Hey Martin Im not sure how to make the font in this box bigger #ZX81", groups: undefined]
```

Can someone help it is really blocking some progress on my app.

Comment: You are not using `g` flag, so you get the first match only. Did you just want to get non-whitespace chunks? `message.match(/\S+/g)`?

Comment: hey @WiktorStribiżew just exactly what i specified in the example above. I didnt consider somone typing a lot of white space, so maybe yes if a person types "thisisaword {a lot of whitespace here}" then capture that as well up tot he next word.

Comment: Then `\S+\s*` would match a "word" followed by optional whitespace characters, and `/g` will match all occurrences.

Comment: how do i get it to also match #hashtags and @username?

Comment: `message.match(/\s*\S+\s*/g)` matches any 1+ non-whitespace chars and all leading/trailing whitespaces if any, so it covers hashtags, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all non-whitespace char chunks with any adjoining whitespace, you can use

```js
message.match(/\s*\S+\s*/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2vB63j/1). The `g` flag will make it extract all matches of

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `\S+` - one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const message = "RegExr #was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple. Edit the Expression & Text to see matches.";
console.log(message.match(/\s*\S+\s*/g));
```